# Convert Stored Procedure to Simple T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, restore-points

I am new to SQL Server and currently learning it. I got following stored procedure which I don't understand.

```
-- declare a new TABLE variable
DECLARE @Products TABLE
(RowNumber INT,
ProductID INT,
Name VARCHAR(50),
Description VARCHAR(5000),
Price MONEY,
Image1FileName VARCHAR(50),
Image2FileName VARCHAR(50),
OnDepartmentPromotion bit,
OnCatalogPromotion bit)

-- populate the table variable with the complete list of products
INSERT INTO @Products
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Product.ProductID),
Product.ProductID, Name,
SUBSTRING(Description, 1, @DescriptionLength) + '...' AS Description, Price,
Image1FileName, Image2FileName, OnDepartmentPromotion, OnCatalogPromotion
FROM Product INNER JOIN ProductCategory
ON Product.ProductID = ProductCategory.ProductID
WHERE ProductCategory.CategoryID = @CategoryID
-- return the total number of products using an OUTPUT variable
SELECT @HowManyProducts = COUNT(ProductID) FROM @Products
-- extract the requested page of products
SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Price, Image1FileName,
Image2FileName, OnDepartmentPromotion, OnCatalogPromotion
FROM @Products
WHERE RowNumber > (@PageNumber - 1) * @ProductsPerPage
AND RowNumber <= @PageNumber * @ProductsPerPage
```

Please! Convert above stored procedure into simple t-sql statements for me so that I get these points. I will really appreciate your work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this homework?  If so, then you should tag it as homework. Also you should show what you have tried to do.

Comment: No one here is going to do your work for you. If you need help with a specific issue, change your question and let us know that you applied some effort to the problem. Otherwise, you're not likely to get any help at all.

Comment: restore-points according to the tags. But that aside I am reading the current question as: "how to convert a tsql procedure into tsql". That probably is not what the poster is trying to ask

Comment: @Eddy: Very much like my impression. But in the end it seems a little bit clearer: *'Convert above stored procedure into **simple** t-sql statements…'* So maybe the problem is the script is too difficult for the OP to penetrate?

Comment: Maybe but if the OP doesn't feel a need to try to explain his question a bit better I don't feel an urge to spent my time helping him

Comment: Perhaps if you can't understand what that is doing by reading Books Online (SQL Server help files), you are in the wrong profession. It's really pretty simple stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work (I didn't test it):

```
--extract the requested page of products
SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Price, Image1FileName,
Image2FileName, OnDepartmentPromotion, OnCatalogPromotion
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Product.ProductID) AS RowNumber,
Product.ProductID, Name,
SUBSTRING(Description, 1, @DescriptionLength) + '...' AS Description, Price,
Image1FileName, Image2FileName, OnDepartmentPromotion, OnCatalogPromotion
FROM Product INNER JOIN ProductCategory
ON Product.ProductID = ProductCategory.ProductID
WHERE ProductCategory.CategoryID = @CategoryID
    ) A
WHERE RowNumber > (@PageNumber - 1) * @ProductsPerPage
AND RowNumber <= @PageNumber * @ProductsPerPage

-- return the total number of products using an OUTPUT variable
SELECT COUNT(ProductID) AS ProductCount FROM Product INNER JOIN ProductCategory
ON Product.ProductID = ProductCategory.ProductID
WHERE ProductCategory.CategoryID = @CategoryID
```